What is "stored" when dragging a file under Windows?
This question is more general. I wonder what is happening when a file is dragged and moved under Windows.
a) The path is stored temporary while dragging and the folder or location where you drop the file takes this path to move the file.
b) The bytes are stored so the file can be "reassembled" at the location where you drop it to.
Option b) would explain why it is possible to copy a file, delete it and paste it in MS Word for example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#formats-for-transferring-file-system-objects
